# combine all css files in to one file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hello genius programmers. can you help me to combine this all css files into one file

```
   <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/header.css' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/body.css' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/sidebar.css' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/footer.css' />
```

i want to combine all css file into one.
ex:

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/all.css' />
```

Comment: Just copy all and paste them into one file.

Comment: just copy all text on each css file and paste on `all.css` file. and everything is done.

Comment: but i want to become that format where in each part of my website is in different css file .. like my code above ..

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141931/Combine-Multiple-CSS-Files-into-One-File-and-Minif and http://www.shrinker.ch/

Comment: If you want to collect all styles from each css/sass files to one and add to index html, the better way to setup your project with [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). If i understand you right.

Comment: @Ryan so you want them separate on your machine but the client should receive just one, is that correct? Also, please don't add irrelevant tags - this has absolutely nothing to do with MySQL, although it _might_ be related to PHP if you want a PHP-based solution.

Comment: Why don't you use SASS or SCSS? You can maintain your separate scss files and merge them into one CSS. Many IDE have SCSS transpiling support.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily in PHP. And a very formal method of doing and including is that. Most of them are following up this method alone.

Create a PHP file called `styling.php` and you can include all the css files over to that PHP file and then you can include it into your file.

**styling.php**

Under this file you can have the following code.

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/header.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/body.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/sidebar.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/footer.css' />
```

And in the PHP file you can call like this with the help of `include()`

`include()` - The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

> `include()` will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include('styling.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And when you view the pagesource it will display all the links separately.

Some More for clear understanding of `include()`

**Solution One:**

---

**vars.php**

```
<?php
$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
include 'vars.php';
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple
?>
```

**Solution Two**

---

Assume we have a standard footer file called "footer.php", that looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " W3Schools.com</p>";
?>
```

To include the footer file in a page, use the include statement:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope so you can understand better with my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

A rough 'n' ready way in which you could combine all the stylesheets into one would be to create a php script like below and use that in the html when you load the stylehseet.

```
<?php

    /* all.php */

    header( 'Content-Type: text/css' );

    $css=array( '/css/header.css', '/css/body.css', '/css/sidebar.css', '/css/footer.css' );
    $output=array();

    foreach( $css as $file ){
        $output[]=file_exists( $file ) ? file_get_contents( $file ) : '/* error: '.$file.' cannot be found */';
    }
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $output );


?>
```

In the html, include the php file rather than a .css file

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/all.php' />
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are some solutions to automatically run these kind of tasks. You can install [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or any other [tasks runner](http://jpsierens.com/task-runners-a-comparison-between-grunt-gulp-broccoli-and-mimosa/) and specifically for CSS concatenation these package [gulp-concat-css](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/gulp-concat-css).

Install:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-concat-css
```

Once it is installed you can add a task on your `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concatCss('css/all.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Execute:

```
$ gulp
```

Than your html will look like these:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/all.css" />
```